# Is there a way to set the x-axis to min and max value in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, max, axis, min

Data:

```
Month<-c(jan,feb,mar,apr,may)
Values(10,5,8,12,4)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to set the x axis to min and max values without hardcoding it. For example instead of hard coding coord_cartesian(ylim = c(4, 12)) is there a way to just assign y axis to max and min so the graph automatically sets the limits at 4 and 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can extract the `range` from the 'Values' column

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Month, y = Values)) + 
     geom_col() + 
     coord_cartesian(ylim = range(df1$Values))
```

-output

[image]

---

If we need to change the tick marks, use `scale_y_continuous`

```
rng_values <- range(df1$Values) -  c(2, 0)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Month, y = Values)) + 
     geom_col() + 
     coord_cartesian(ylim = rng_values ) + 
     scale_y_continuous(breaks = do.call(seq, 
        c(as.list(rng_values),
            list(by = 0.5))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Month = month.abb[1:5], Values = c(10, 5, 8, 12, 4))
```

Comment: it works thank you. Just wondering if there is a way to control the granularity when doing range(df$Values)

Comment: @Gokul `range` returns the min and max as a vector.  Can you describe what you meant by granularity here.  If you want you can use `c(min(df$Values), max(df$Values))` as well

Comment: Instead of 4, 6, 8,10 is there a way to 4, 4.5, 5 5.5, 6, 6.5 and so on or is there a way to start certain values below min and go certain values above max so for example the graph goes from 2 to 14 just wondering if its possible or not

Comment: thank you very much just one more thing is there a way to start certain values below min and go certain values above max so for example for the graph to go from 2 to 14 just wondering if its possible or not

Comment: @Gokul You can subtract `c(2, 0)` from the range.  Updated the post